# How to get the last value of every month in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have three fields, `id`, `date` and `qty` in my DB. I want to group them by the `id` and find the `qty` which is the latest quantity of every month. So for every month, the `date` with the latest day of every month, the `qty` will be returned for it.

If the input is

```
[
  {
    "id": "ABC",
    "date": "2020-10-02 15:03:00.00",
    "qty": 500,
  },
  {
    "id": "ABC",
    "date": "2020-10-31 20:22:00.00",
    "qty": 100,
  },
  {
    "id": "ABC",
    "date": "2020-11-03 04:22:00.00",
    "qty": 200,
  },
  {
    "id": "ABC",
    "date": "2020-11-18 04:22:00.00",
    "qty": 50,
  },
  {
    "id": "ABC1",
    "date": "2020-11-05 04:22:00.00",
    "qty": 5000,
  },
  {
    "id": "ABC1",
    "date": "2020-11-15 04:22:00.00",
    "qty": 4580,
  },
]
```

then the output should be

```
[
  {
    "id": "ABC",
    "qtys": [
      {
        "date": "2020-10-31 20:22:00.00",
        "qty": 100
      },
      {
        "date": "2020-11-18 04:22:00.00",
        "qty": 50
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "ABC1",
    "qtys": [
      {
        "date": "2020-11-15 04:22:00.00",
        "qty": 4580
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$addFields` to convert `date` field from string type to date type, if its already date type then ignore this stage
- `$sort` by `date` in descending order
- `$group` by `id`, `month` and `year` after extracting from `date` field
  using `$year` and `$month` to get first document
- `$group` by only `id` and construct array of quantities in `qtys`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $addFields: { date: { $toDate: "$date" } } },
  { $sort: { date: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        id: "$id",
        month: { $month: "$date" },
        year: { $year: "$date" }
      },
      qtys: { $first: { date: "$date", qty: "$qty" } }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.id",
      qtys: { $push: "$qtys" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OHULf3d6Q2F)

Comment: You missed year also. If another years data is added, then this query adds them into one.